# How to show AlertDialog as soon as Fragment created

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'd like to show an AlertDialog (with a couple of Radio Button buttons and an OK button) as soon as a fragment is created.

Where is the best place to call the dialog fragment? I have tried in onViewCreated() and on onResume() and both work, but I am not sure what's best practice.

Also, to ensure the dialog isn't shown every time the fragment is stopped/recreated due, for example, to screen rotation, I have created Boolean value called mShowDialog and set it to 'true' in onCreate() then used an 'If' statement to decide whether the dialog should be shown (see below for example).

```
onCreate(){
    //.... 
    mShowDialog = true;
}

onResume(){
    if (mShowDialog){
        //....show dialog code
        // set mShowDialog to false to ensure code executed only once
        mShowDialog = false;
    }
}
```

Is the above code the best way of fulfilling both requirements?

Btw, I am fairly new to programming.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice for this is to inflate dialog in `onCreateView()` method of fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create it from the activity adding the fragment, I've had good luck with adding a `FragmentListener` to my fragments and setting it from the activity. This is my basic `BaseFragment` class that all my fragments extend:

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    public Context context;
    public Activity activity;

    public FragmentListener fragmentListener;

    private boolean attached = false;

    public BaseFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        if (!isAttached()) {
            this.context = activity;
            this.activity = activity;

            if (this.fragmentListener != null) {
                this.fragmentListener.onAttached();
            }

            setAttached(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (!isAttached()) {
            this.context = context;
            this.activity = (Activity) context;

            if (this.fragmentListener != null) {
                this.fragmentListener.onAttached();
            }

            setAttached(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        setAttached(false);
        if (this.fragmentListener != null){
            this.fragmentListener.onDetached();
        }
    }

    public void setFragmentListener(FragmentListener fragmentListener) {
        this.fragmentListener = fragmentListener;
    }

    public View.OnClickListener onBackTapped = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    };

    public boolean isAttached() {
        return attached;
    }

    public void setAttached(boolean attached) {
        this.attached = attached;
    }

    public boolean isPermissionGranted(String permission){
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    public boolean ifShouldShowRationaleForPermission(String permission){
        return ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission);
    }

    public void showPermissionRequest(Activity activity, int requestCode, String... permissions){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, requestCode);
    }
}
```

This way, I can do this in my activity:

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
myfragment.setFragmentListener(new FragmentListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAttached() {
        // Stuff I want to do when it is attached
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetached() {
        // Stuff I want to do when it is detached
    }
});

fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, myFragment)
        .commit();
```

And then I can add whatever code I want when the fragment does it's various stuff.

Good luck!